Shapefile not converting to raster file
I downloaded a river shapefile via OSM. I need to convert it to raster. However, when I use raster converter, it comes out empty. What do you think is the cause of this?



Best to post a shot of your tool parameters and the OSM attribute table.

You specified 0 as the value to burn and 0 as the NoData value so your entire output will be 0 i.e NoData.
Use a different value as the value to burn, e.g. 1.


Also the raster resolution doesn't seem optimal (if meter 0,5 seem small, if degree 0,5 seem big...) but it really depend on the intended raster use
